# What is the file name of the default background?

Tags: 12.04, default

I was trying to change this picture, and forget the name of the background.

Tried warty-final-ubuntu.png and warty-final-ubuntu.jpg but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using

`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-artwork`

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I realized that, the problem was about the resolution...

Answer (score 8):

The name is: `warty-final-ubuntu.png` and it is inside `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

Answer (score 2):

It is called warty-final-ubuntu.png just like you said but if you are searching for it I don't think it will show up since it is in usr folder. It is in filesystem/usr/share/backgrounds Also I don't think you can change it as I can't put any other images in that folder or rename one in it already.

Comment: I used gksu nautilus /usr/share/backgrounds and deleted it. Put another image with the same name. The image under the login screen disappeared. I downloaded the image again and placed to same location (renamed as warty-final...png). Still no images. Thanks for replies. 

Thought, the problem is about the name. But not, I think there is something different that I can not guess.

Comment: With Ubuntu Tweak you can choose the login screen background. To install paste this at a terminal: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak` See a picture here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6qyZc.png and more informatione here:

Comment: As I said, I am using 12.04 beta, Ubuntu Tweak is already installed in my OS. But the problem is that, Under the Login Theme Tab, There is "login screen logo" with a button, which has no image in it. There is no background or option related information.

Comment: Ups, it seems my header is edited. Sorry. Let me repeat, I am using 12.04 beta :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Can't you click over where it was supposed to be the image background?

Comment: Also you can edit this file: `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf` and add `background=/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png` more info here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/tool-change-lightdm-wallpaper-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: If I enter this command to bash, gedit opens but if I use "ls -lh" under /etc/lightdm/, there is no unity-greeter.conf. Only "lightdm.conf" and "users.conf".

But I will try to save it instead. I am going to take screenshots and share them too. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: http://i42.tinypic.com/6z0wtk.png this one is related with the bash results. I am now taking the screenshot of LDM.

Comment: And the login screen (sorry for the light problem.): http://i42.tinypic.com/2vbafwo.jpg